# in web.config rewrite, how do I target ONLY the URL, and not all URLs that begin with that

Tags: windows, iis, url-rewriting, web-config, windows-server-2012

I have gotten the rewrite rules working on web.config, but I am having an issue where it matches all URLs that start with the specified URL, and I need it to ONLY match the exact URL, not everything that starts with that URL.

```
<rule name="Rewrite training to SEO friendly version">
  <match url="^training" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="training/web-training-courses" />
</rule>
```

This is my existing code.  It will rewrite **domain.com/training** to go to **domain.com/training/web-training-courses** as intended, but it also will rewrite anything else that starts with **domain.com/training**, such as **domain.com/training/courses/css** .
I do not want it to rewrite when there is additional info after the word "training". Is there a special character or something that tells the rewrite engine to only match that exact URL?

I am on Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Use the dollar sign:

```
<match url="^training$" />
```